# How does one store data into an environment?

Tags: r, quantmod

I specifically want to be able to run a trading strategy multiple times while changing the parameters without the code pulling the historical prices every time the code runs again.

I am using the getSymbols function from the quantmod package and was wondering how I could store the pulled data into the environment so that when the code runs the 2nd,3rd,..., etc time it does not need to take forever to pull the 500+ financial data per ticker. Thank you so much.

Comment: Am I missing something, or does `save` not do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the OP title's question, "how to store data in an environment", you need to use the function assign():

```
foo=new.env() # create environment.
assign(x="a",value=10,envir=foo) # assigns value 10 to variable 'a' in environment 'foo'.
ls(envir=foo) # lists variables in environment 'foo'.
get(x="a",envir=foo) # get the value of variable 'a' in environment 'foo'.
```

And this will also work to get the variable value, as mentioned in another reply:

```
foo$a
```

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the `?getSymbols` help page. For example

```
data.env <- new.env()
getSymbols("YHOO", env=data.env)
```

and then you get the data with

```
data.env$YHOO
```

If this fails to answer your question, please be more specific about the code you are trying to run.